# Route [student.contact] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

After I have added this code in StudentController

```
public function contact(Student $student)
{
    $classes = Grade::latest()->get();
    $parents = Parents::with('user')->latest()->get();

    return view('backend.students.contact', compact('classes','parents','student'));
}
```

and in index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('student.contact',$student->id) }}" class="ml-1">
                            <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current text-gray-600" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="pen-square" class="svg-inline--fa fa-envelope-square fa-w-14" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 480H48c-26.5 0-48-21.5-48-48V80c0-26.5 21.5-48 48-48h352c26.5 0 48 21.5 48 48v352c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48zM238.1 177.9L102.4 313.6l-6.3 57.1c-.8 7.6 5.6 14.1 13.3 13.3l57.1-6.3L302.2 242c2.3-2.3 2.3-6.1 0-8.5L246.7 178c-2.5-2.4-6.3-2.4-8.6-.1zM345 165.1L314.9 135c-9.4-9.4-24.6-9.4-33.9 0l-23.1 23.1c-2.3 2.3-2.3 6.1 0 8.5l55.5 55.5c2.3 2.3 6.1 2.3 8.5 0L345 199c9.3-9.3 9.3-24.5 0-33.9z"></path></svg>
                        </a>
```

I got this error :

```
Route [student.contact] not defined
```

Do anyone has an idea about this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: post your route code

Comment: Have you actually defined a route with the name `student.contact`? If yes, please post it. If no, then that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply You can add one line of code in project/routes/web.php file (here you didn't define any route so error is occurs )

```
 Route::get('student/contact/{id}', 'StudentsController@contact')->name('student.contact');
```